# Even and odd functions using integrals

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

If $f: [-r, r] \to\mathbb{R}$ is an even function, show that $g(x) = \cos(nx)$ is an even function and $h(x) = \sin(nx)$ is an odd function. Consider:

$\int_{-r}^{r} f(x)\cos(nx)dx = 2\int_{0}^{r} f(x)\cos(nx)dx$

and $\int_{-r}^{r} f(x)\sin(nx)dx = 0$

Deduce analogous results considering $f$ as an odd function.

Comment: The problem may not be quoted accurately. But to show for example the thing about $\int_{-r}^r f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx$, break up into two parts, $-r$ to $0$ and $0$ to $r$. For the negative part, make the change of variable $u=-x$.

Comment: Some unclear parts:  1. Is $f$ integrable in some sense?  2. Do you mean $g(x)= f(x)\cdot \cos(nx)$ and $h(x)= f(x)\cdot \sin(nx)$?  3. Should the integral identities be proved too?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be an odd function then

$\int_{-r}^{r}f(x)\cos(nx)dx=\int_{-r}^{0}f(x)\cos(nx)dx+\int_{0}^{r}f(x)\cos(nx)dx$

$=-\int_{-r}^{0}f(-(-x))\cos(-n(-x))(-1)dx+\int_{0}^{r}f(x)\cos(nx)dx$

$=-\int_{-r}^{0}-f(-x)\cos(n(-x))(-1)dx+\int_{0}^{r}f(x)\cos(nx)dx$

$=\int_{r}^{0}f(x)cos(nx)dx+\int_{0}^{r}f(x)\cos(nx)dx$

$-\int_{0}^{r}f(x)\cos(nx)dx+\int_{0}^{r}f(x)\cos(nx)dx=0$.

Similarly,

$\int_{-r}^{r}f(x)\sin(nx)dx=\int_{-r}^{0}f(x)\sin(nx)dx+\int_{0}^{r}f(x)\sin(nx)dx$

$-\int_{-r}^{0}f(-x)\sin(n(-x))(-1)dx+\int_{0}^{r}f(x)\sin(nx)dx$

$2\int_{0}^{r}f(x)\sin(nx)dx$.